# Where does the name eigenvalue come from?

Tags: mathematics, linear-algebra

Who introduced the concept of eigenvalues and eigenvectors and where does the name come from? Is there a connection with the German word "eigen"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Exactly; see [Eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Overview) :

> The prefix [eigen-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eigen-) is adopted from the German word eigen for "proper", "inherent"; "own", "individual", "special"; "specific", "peculiar", or "characteristic".

It was David Hilbert who introduced the terms *Eigenwert* and *Eigenfunktion*; see:

- David Hilbert, [Grundzüge einer allgemeinen Theorie der linearen Integralgleichungen](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/u/umhistmath/acu8916.0003.001/10?page=root;rgn=full+text;size=100;view=pdf;q1=eigenwert) (1904); see e.g. page X for *Eigenwert* and *Eigenfunktion* [see [here](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~stewart/FHS.pdf) for the English translation].